# What does JQuery UI add here?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

Recently, I watched a video on YouTube where someone made an horizontal slider using JQuery and JQuery UI. 
I successfully recreated the slider, however, *I do not understand what JQuery UI exactly does here.* If I take it out, the slider won't work. If any of you could help me out by telling me what it is that JQuery UI adds here, it would really be appreciated!

This is the code for the slider:

**HTML**

```
  <body>
    <div class="slider">
        <img id="1" src="1.jpg">
        <img id="2" src="2.jpg">
        <img id="3" src="3.jpg">
    </div>

    <script src="../../../Users/Dave/Downloads/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../../../Users/Dave/Desktop/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script src="behavior.js"></script>
    </body>
```

**CSS**

```
.slider{
    width: 600px;
    height: 400px;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 30 auto;

}

.slider img{
    width: 600px;
    height: 400px;
    display: none;
}
```

**JQuery**

```
function Slider(){
    $(".slider #1").show("fade", 500);  
    $(".slider #1").delay(5500).hide("slide", {direction: 'left'}, 500);
    var sc = $(".slider img").size();
    var count = 2;

    setInterval(function(){
        $(".slider #"+count).show("slide", {direction: 'right'} , 500);
        $(".slider #"+count).delay(5500).hide("slide", {direction: 'left'}, 500);   

        if(count == sc){
            count = 1;  
        }else{
            count = count+1;
        }
    }, 6500);

}


$(document).ready(function() {
    Slider();
});
```

Like I said, the slider works exactly how I want it too, I understand the code and how it works, I just don't understand why I need JQuery UI for this. What methods/functions/etc. does it add here? Why doesn't it work without JQuery UI?

Comment: Compare [`show()`](http://api.jquery.com/show/) vs. [`show()`](http://api.jqueryui.com/show/)

Answer (score 1):

The code is using [jQuery UI's slide effect](http://jqueryui.com/effect/)s that is not available in the jQuery Core